# C++ - Loading Microsoft Symbols for an Offline VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, offline, symbols

New Developer/Engineer working on a project where I can't find my "msvcr120d.i386.pdb" file from my "msvcr120d.dll". The issue arose when I prompted my application to run a specific tasking, and I don't want to load code due to the fact that it is literally scaling different classes. I really just believe that I need to get all the Microsoft Symbols so I can path them locally on my Machine. The machine is offline and can never access the Internet, but I do have a machine accessing the Internet and would like to know how to just get the files without my development machine requiring access to the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download them from Microsoft to install locally.

[Get them from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028.aspx)

Comment: This is a great resource, but instead of simply plowing through each installation, does anyone know where msvcr120d.i386 is located?

Comment: Sorry, this is the only way I know to get the symbols to work without directly referencing the MS symbol server.  It should be a single download/installation for your OS version, and contains all the symbols for the OS.  Other than that you would have to setup the symbol server as a resource which isn't an option for you.  Also the public symbol server doesn't allow you to browse it, so you can't find a link to that one specific file.

Comment: The only problem now is convincing the IT people to simply scan 7.5GBs of DVD's. "Is this the end solution?". Yeah I'll get back to you on that one. The reality of this all comes from the IT people wanting me to step away from Visual C++ 6.0 and utilize current versions of Visual Studio like 2013. OH THE HORROR.